# Find the minimum sum of two non-adjacent elements in an unsorted array in O(n) time?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

input : {5,3,1,2,4,1}

output : 2

Is it possible to do this in O(N) time ?

Answer (score 5):

You can find the three smallest elements in O(n), also storing their indices. At least two of those will be non-adjacent, so summing them will give the desired result.